# Can sites detect auto-refreshing tools?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox

I don't want to get into details of my situation, but it's like this:

I'm part of a website and so are other people. On this site, we are all waiting for something to appear on the site, but one must refresh the site to see if anything new appeared. The site rules explicitly mention that auto-refreshing tools are prohibited.

If I for example use a browser extension that would refresh the site every minute, could the site detect that? Do these extensions make the same request to the site as if I clicked the refresh button? I'm sure they could detect the refreshing intervals, but that can be avoided by a random timer. So what is the most undetectable way of autorefreshing a site?

Comment: There is no way to detect a difference between a random auto refresh and a random manual refresh.  They look identical to the server.  What sounds silly is that a refresh is required to see the updated data at all.  If the site just uses a webSocket to "push" the update to the connected browser as soon as it happens on the server, then this whole argument would be moot and you'd have a level playing field without having to solve the auto-refresh detection issue at all.

Answer (score 1):

Different extensions work differently.some use the javascript reload function, some will just grab the url and replace window.location with it effectively making another GET request
The only difference in the actual request will be whether or not cache control is set etc..so they might use that for detection.So definitely you need to take a look in the documentation to see how the request is being issued in that specific extension

As far as circumstantial evidence they can cookie you,use local data storage,use your ip address to determine you are the same user which in that case you would need to find a workaround for each one